# How do I get my own AMIs with AWS Tools for Powershell?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, aws-powershell

I am trying out AWS Powershell tool. What is the command to load AMI image I created in my environment?
Apparently get-ec2image command loads all the available image on the market, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The detailed syntax of the Get-EC2Image is

```
Get-EC2Image-ImageId <String[]>-Owner <String[]>-ExecutableUser <String[]>-Filter <Filter[]>
```

So in your case it would workout to be, assuming 123456789 being your AWS Account Number.

```
Get-EC2Image -Owner '123456789'
```

Answer (score 1):

Get-EC2Image is what you need, you just need to set the `-Owner` parameter to 'self', like so:

```
PS C:/> Get-EC2Image -owner self
```

Here's an example where you can select your own AMIs, filtered by AMI Name (the AMI name given during image creation, not the [re-assignable tag "name"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html)):

```
PS C:/> Get-EC2Image -Owners self -Filters @{ Name='name'; Values='amiName' }
```

From the documentation:

> In this context, [self] refers to the user who corresponds to the
>   credentials with which the cmdlet is invoked.

More info available at the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-ec2-get-amis.html) for Get-EC2Image.

Comment: Thank you. How do I pick a particular image called "TestImage" from my list and launch a new instance from that image? and assign a static IP address if its possible?? :-/

Comment: @minisch You should create a new question to ask these, comments on Stack Overflow are meant to be ephemeral whenever possible and are hard to use for answers because of formatting limitations. But generally, for using names you'll want to use the `-Filter` parameter (see example by typing `get-help get-ec2image -full` in powershell).  For static IPs you'll want to read on [Elastic IPs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html).

Comment: @minisch I've updated the answer to include an example of the name filter.